# ignore deprecate classes in findbugs 1.2

Tags: findbugs, java1.4

I would like to know if there is any possibility to ignore deprecated classes from findbugs analysis?
i am using Java 1.4, findbugs 1.2 versions

Regards
Sailaja

Comment: I don't know if this was supported in FindBugs 1.2 already, but there are filters: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html ... you can't filter by annotation (so it's not a direct solution, and I will not submit it as an answer), but maybe you could a) manually filter some of the worst deprecated classes/packages b) write a script that would list all deprecated classes, and generate the FindBugs filter xml.